# Xcode write the data base but still empty

Tags: objective-c, ios, database, xcode, sqlite

First of all I am from spain so sorry about my grammar. I am writing some data to a sqlite data base, here is my code:

I have allredy checked that the data base, table and column names are ok, when I change anything I get errors, so the code its working properly.

```
@try {

    NSFileManager *fileMgr=[NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSString *dbPath=[self database]; 
    BOOL succes=[fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
    if(!succes)
    {
        NSLog(@"Cannot locate database '%@'.",dbPath);
    }
    if (!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &dbcapturas)==SQLITE_OK)) {
        NSLog(@"An error has occured: %@",sqlite3_errmsg(dbcapturas));
    }

    //sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;
    NSString *asd=numero.text;
    NSString *insertStatement=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO captura(key,tecnico, fecha,provincia,municipio,latitud,longitud,altura,familia,especie,numero,comentario)Values(\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")",asd,tecnico,fechaHora,tecnico,municipio,latitud,longitud,altura,tecnico,animal,asd,coment];
    char *error;
    if((sqlite3_exec(dbcapturas, [insertStatement UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &error))==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Person inserted.");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %s", error);
    }
} @catch (NSException *exception) { 
    NSLog(@"fail"); 
}
@finally {
        NSLog(@"cerrada");
    sqlite3_close(dbcapturas);
}
```

the first time I click on the save button I get:

> 2012-07-04 12:17:45.644 adasdasd[1783:f803] Person inserted.

and the second time I get :

> 2012-07-04 12:29:18.959 adasdasd[1840:f803] Error: column key is not
>   unique

So my code should be ok but when I open the database with the firefox add-on its totally empty, any idea?

Edit: I now call

```
-(NSString *)database{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"capturas.sqlite"];
}
```

but now I get a error saying me: no such table: capturas
 I have a table capturas in my db 100% sure

Comment: You'd probably want to use FMDB, which is a better wrapper/code usage for standard SQL operations.

Comment: sorry I am noob, can you be more specific or send me a example plz? no idea about what FMDB means

Comment: https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

Comment: @Insane_Poyo what Parag said. It's a wrapper for SQL functions, that you use it so that you won't have to use the native functions of IOS. Instead of writing 5-10 lines of code initializing sqlite you can use 2-3 and the rest is your business logic.

Comment: @Insane_Poyo For pity's sake - *"sorry I am noob, can you be more specific or send me a example plz? no idea about what FMDB means"* Did you even **bother** to search before you posted that. How can you expect help when you don't help yourself?

Comment: Also you cannot change the database located in main bundle, because it's readonly. You'll have to move the database to nsdocuments directory (or somewhere writeable) after the first initialization of your app.

Comment: thx a lot Panagiotis!! changing it right now

Comment: still trying to make it work but can't handle it, maybe you can post a code example about how to move the db from main bundle to  nsdocuments directory? thx

Comment: I am calling a function now when I click the button to get the db to a string, editing my post

Answer (score 0):

When setting up your table, the column `key` is probably indexed or defined to be unique or auto-incrementing. When you do the insert, you pass a specific key, namely whatever is in the variable `asd`. If you try that the second time, you will get the sqlite error because the column `key` has to be unique. If it is auto increment, just leave it out and it will be filled automatically.

The first entry should be in the database if you closed it correctly. Make sure you are checking the correct copy of the database with Firefox (test by inserting a dummy record in your app delegate, for example).

Comment: I did it on porpouse to check It was writing the data to database, and I am checking the correct database file, I guess it is saving the data to a temp file but doesnt reach the database.

Comment: One way is to do it without your try-catch-finally. It seems the finally is not called. You could simply call `sqlite3_close` before.